# How to know which card is tapped in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am making my first flutter app (A coffee shop), in this I have accessed data from Firebase Cloudstore and displayed it in the form of card.

Now I have provided the user with the feature of customizing order
for that I have to know which item he is customizing and hence I need to know which card the user has tapped.

Here is my code snippet:

```
      child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        return showModalBottomSheet<void>(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
          )
        ),
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            child: CustomOrder(),
            height: 400.0,
            width: 350.0,
          );
        },
      );
    },
    child: Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(  
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),  
      ),
      elevation: 10,   
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/coff1.PNG'),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Text(
                 '${itemslist[index]["item_name"]}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 38.0,
                  fontFamily: 'GrandHotel',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.brown[800]
                ),
                // textAlign: TextAlign.left
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Text(
                '${itemslist[index]["price"]}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                  fontFamily: 'GrandHotel',
                  color: Colors.brown[800]
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Text(
                '${itemslist[index]["desc"]}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                  fontFamily: 'GrandHotel',
                  color: Colors.brown[800]
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            FlatButton.icon(
              color: Colors.brown[400],
              onPressed: (){}, 
              icon: Icon(Icons.add), 
              label: Text(
                "Add to cart",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.brown[800]
                ),
              ),
              ),
              
          ]
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are using a listView.builder but didn't attach it to your code properly, but you are accessing this `[index]` in your code.

Therefore, in your onpressed button in the bottom,

```
 onPressed: (){
 print(itemslist[index]["item_name"]);} // should print your tapped item's name, and then you can do whatever you want if you have reached this far.
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my doubt,
I just added print(itemsList[index]['id']) in onTap(){} function
thanks a lot!!.

Comment: You are most welcome! Please consider marking this as the answer to your question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap each separate card with their own GestureDetector. If you need more instruction for implementing this, just let me know in the comments.

Comment: Actually I am accessing the data from firebase so if it has 20 documents then it is difficult to wrap 20 cards. So can you elaborate more?

Comment: @AditiSingh It's not quite clear to me what your layout is. If you're receiving a list of documents from firebase and you'd like to display each one, then I would use ListView.builder. I could probably help more if I was able to see more of your code.

Comment: @AditiSingh As Eli Front said if you are getting multiple document then you used just us a ListView and use a List.generate for the children or simply use the ListView.builder, only then you will be able to use the index to find which card was clicked

Comment: Yes, I am using list view builder and returning a card